# Cómo puedo devolver un objeto en lugar de un id en dropdown button en flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy retornando un id de un dropdown button y no está mal, pero lo que deseo es devolver un objeto y en la lista mostrar una descripción y devolver el objeto porque necesito agregar un elemento una lista cada vez que se selecciona un item y se le da click al botón de confirmar, ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
String opcionInstitucion = "1006";
selectInstitcionFinanciera() {
return FutureBuilder(
    future: API.instance.getInstitucionFinanciera(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<List<InstitucionFinanciera>> snapshot) {
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? SearchableDropdown.single(
              hint: Text('Selecciona una institución financiera'),
              value: opcionInstitucion,
              items: _institucion.map((accountType) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: accountType.idFinanciera.toString(),
                  child: Text(accountType.descripcion),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (opt) {
                setState(() {
                  opcionInstitucion = opt;
                  print("INSTITUCION: $opcionInstitucion");
                });
              },
            )
          : Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: HexColor("FFCB00")),
              ),
            );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solo cambia el valor que asignas, en lugar de enviar un String, envía un objeto, que sería `accountType`.

Luego de eso `opt` será del tipo de objeto que enviaste. Es decir, será un `AccountType`.

```dart
SearchableDropdown.single(
              hint: Text('Selecciona una institución financiera'),
              value: opcionInstitucion,
              items: _institucion.map((accountType) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: accountType,
                  child: Text(accountType.descripcion),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (opt) {
                setState(() {
                  opcionInstitucion = opt;
                  print("INSTITUCION: $opcionInstitucion");
                });
              },
            )
```

Ahora, para que esto haga efecto, tu clase `AccountType`, deberá sobreescribir unos métodos para que el widget pueda comparar objetos.

```dart
class AccountType {
  final String idFinanciera;

  const AccountType(this.idFinanciera);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
    other is AccountType &&
    runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
    idFinanciera == other.idFinanciera;

  @override
  int get hashCode => idFinanciera.hashCode;
}
```